# phantomjs get different outerHTML from chrome Inspect Element

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using the following script to get outerHTML of "chart_anchor" element.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system'), address, myid;

if (system.args.length != 3) 
{
  console.log('Usage: ' + system.args[0] + ' <some URL> <ElementId>');
  phantom.exit();
}
address = system.args[1];
myid = system.args[2];
page.open(address, function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status + " " + address);
  if(status === "success") {
   var html = page.evaluate(function(elemid){
    return document.getElementById(elemid).outerHTML; // "chart-section"
   }, myid);
   page.render('example.png');
   console.log(html);
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

the following command is used to get outerHTML for the node, but the output is different from "Inspect Element" in chrome. Can some expert help me to get the same result? 
Thanks a lot.

./phantomjs l2.js "http://www.google.com/finance?chdnp=1&chdd=1&chds=1&chdv=1&chvs=maximized&chdeh=0&chfdeh=0&chdet=1423200847674&chddm=1172.9999999999998&chls=IntervalBasedLine&q=NASDAQ%3AC&ntsp=0&fct=big&ei=TlLUVJnyAdDlqAG7r4H4Dg" chart_anchor

result from phantomjs

```
<div id="chart_anchor" class="id-chart_anchor"><div id="image_chart"><table><tbody><tr><td class="itxt" align="left"><span class="linkbtn" onclick="_changeImage &amp;&amp; _changeImage('1d',60, 1);">1d</span> <span class="linkbtn"
```

...more

from chrome 
    `<div id="chart_anchor" class="id-chart_anchor"><embed src="/finance/s/Med12Cbcdb8/chart9.swf?hl=en&amp;gl=us" width="100%" height="340" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" menu="false" name="chartElement" id="chartElement" wmode="opaque" flashvars="lcId=142323` ...much more

I have not made it work yet, but the following links seems to be very relevant.
http://www.ryanbridges.org/2013/05/21/putting-the-flash-back-in-phantomjs/

Comment: What is the difference? Please be more specific about what you get and what you expect. You can edit your question to include this information.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You are correct that phantomjs doesn't have flash support. The easiest way to get the same result is of course to get the non-flashversion in both browsers.

Comment: I want to get the same outerHTML as "Inspect Element" feature of Chrome. copy it from a browser manually is a painful work. Now I found a version of phantomjs that supports flash plugin from the url in my question part.

Answer (score 0):

Combined with instructions from the following page, phantomjs output the same outerHTML as Chrome.
http://blog.webogroup.com/2013/04/how-to-setup-completely-headless.html

```
yum install -y xorg-x11-server-Xvfb xorg-x11-server-Xorg xorg-x11-fonts* dbus-x11 xulrunner.x86_64 nspr.x86_64 nss.x86_64
yum install -y libcurl
yum localinstall flash-player-plugin-11.2.202.442-1.mga5.nonfree.x86_64.rpmfind
yum localinstall nspluginwrapper-1.4.4-1.el6_3.i686.rpm
```